# Uno platform: load embedded resource file

Tags: embedded-resource, uno-platform

How do I load an embedded resource for the Android head ? My code, below works for UWP:

```
  Assembly assembly = GetType ().GetTypeInfo ().Assembly;
  string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames ();
  Console.WriteLine ("Resource Names");
  foreach (var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine ("  " + name);
  using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream (Source))
  {
    bmpSrc = SKBitmap.Decode (stream);
  }
```

And, the XAML is

```
  <controls:ExpandableImage 
    ...
    Source="UnoTest.Assets.icons.folder_tab.png"
  />
```

The file resides in `UnoTest.Shared/Assets/` and is marked as "embedded resource".

The debug output shows that one of the "names" is

```
"UnoTest.Droid.Assets.icons.folder_tab.png"
```

indicating that my URI should be referring to the Android head.

EDIT

Ultimately, in this experiment, I am intending to paint the left part of the bitmap in the left of the target area, the right in the right, and fill the middle with an expansion of a vertical stripe from the bitmap's mid section. Then, draw some text over it.

```
private void OnPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
  ...
  // identify left, right halves and a 10px wide swath of the middle of the source bitmap
  SKRect rectSrcLeft = new SKRect(0, 0, bmpSrc.Width / 2, bmpSrc.Height);
  SKRect rectSrcRight = new SKRect(bmpSrc.Width / 2, 0, bmpSrc.Width, bmpSrc.Height);
  SKRect rectSrcMid = new SKRect(bmpSrc.Width / 2 - 5, 0, bmpSrc.Width / 2 + 5, bmpSrc.Height);

  // create a new bitmap containing a 10 pixel wide swatch from middle of bmpSrc
  SKBitmap bmpSrcMid = new SKBitmap(10, bmpSrc.Height);
  using (SKCanvas tempCanvas = new SKCanvas(bmpSrcMid))
  {
    SKRect rectDest = new SKRect(0, 0, rectSrcMid.Width, rectSrcRight.Height);
    tempCanvas.DrawBitmap(bmpSrc, rectSrcMid, rectDest);
  }

  var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;

  using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
  {
    canvas.Save();
    float hDest = canvas.DeviceClipBounds.Height;
    float scale = hDest / (float)bmpSrc.Height;
    canvas.Scale(scale);

    paint.IsAntialias = true;

    // determine dest rect for middle section
    float rightDest = (float)textBounds.Width / scale; // rightmost point of whole target area
    SKRect rectDestMid = new SKRect(rectSrcLeft.Width, 0, rightDest - rectSrcRight.Width, rectSrcRight.Height);

    // left part of tab
    canvas.DrawBitmap(bmpSrc, rectSrcLeft, rectSrcLeft, paint);

    // right part of tab
    {
      SKRect rectDest = new SKRect(rectDestMid.Right, 0, rightDest, rectSrcRight.Height);
      canvas.DrawBitmap(bmpSrc, rectSrcRight, rectDest, paint);
    }

    // mid part of tab
    paint.Shader = SKShader.CreateBitmap(bmpSrcMid,
                                         SKShaderTileMode.Repeat,
                                         SKShaderTileMode.Repeat);
    canvas.DrawRect(rectDestMid, paint);

    canvas.Restore(); // back to orig scale
  }

  using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint { Color = SKColors.Black })
  {
    float leftText = 20; // matches padding in ListPage.xaml
    float bottomText = canvas.DeviceClipBounds.Height / 2 + textCoreHeight / 2;
    canvas.DrawText(Label, new SKPoint(leftText, bottomText), paint);
  }
}
```

The XAML for the control is:

```
<UserControl
  x:Class="UnoTest.Shared.Controls.ExpandableImage"
  ...
  <skia:SKXamlCanvas x:Name="EICanvas" PaintSurface="OnPaintSurface" />
</UserControl>
```

Do I need to write some code to modify the "generic" URI for the Android case ?

Comment: Your sample is not detailed enough unfortunately. You do not provide the code that you use to get to the SKBitmap to something else. Probably having a more detailed sample would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. It is not 100% robust but pretty close. And it's really simple.

```
  if (Source == null)
    return;

  string sourceWithNameSpace = null;
  Assembly assembly = GetType ().GetTypeInfo ().Assembly;
  string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames ();
  foreach (var name in names)
  {
    if (name.EndsWith (Source))
    {
      sourceWithNameSpace = name;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (sourceWithNameSpace == null)
    return;

  using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream (sourceWithNameSpace))
  {
    bmpSrc = SKBitmap.Decode (stream);
  }
```

And, in the XML file, leave off the project head from the Source path, e.g.:

```
    Source="Assets.icons.folder_tab.png"
```

Comment: Nice! That works! Just as a comment, you can also use Linq to filter the name avoiding manually iterating over the list of names. Basically, you could change the  `foreach` block for this line of code `  var sourceWithNameSpace = names.FirstOrDefault(name => name.EndsWith(Source))`. If there is a name that EndsWith your source it will return it otherwise it will return null.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded Resources defined in shared projects are sharing the default namespace of the project referencing that shared project, making the file name different in all projects by default in Uno templates.

You have multiple options:

- Change the default namespace to be the same in all projects.
- Skip the first two dots and use this as the base
- Use a different project (a .NET Standard 2.0 project will do) and place your resources there

Comment: Jérôme - while your solutions are ideologically correct, I came up with a blazingly simply way to resolve this. See my "answer."

Comment: Glad you found it! It is essentially the second solution I mentioned. Note that using `EndsWith` could potentially be matching the wrong path (e.g. looking for `MyFolder.File1.txt` could match `MyOtherFolder.MyFolder.File1.txt` and `MyFolde.File1.txt`).

Comment: Yes, that's a minor weakness. But if you include reasonably uniques paths with the filename, it becomes almost impossible to have a false match. No worse, anyway, than the resource syntax that has . instead of /